# php form: passing on submitted information

Tags: php, jquery, forms

```
if(!isset($_POST['JoinFaction'])) {

echo '<form method="post" action="'.$page_name.'"><dl id="sample" class="dropdown" align="left">'
    .'<dt><a href="#"><span>Recruiting Factions ['.$numrows.']</span>'
    .'</a></dt><dd><ul>';

while($faction_re = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<li><a href="#">'.$faction_re['f_name'].''
    .'<span class="value">'.$faction_re['f_id'].'</span></a></li>';         
}

echo '</ul></dd></dl></td>'
    .'<td class="faction_bgcolour" align="center"><input type="image" '
    .'name="JoinFaction" value="JoinFaction" width="54" height="45" '
    .'src="images/global/game/faction/join_faction.png" /></td></form>';
  //get output as a variable to use in later code
  echo $selected_faction = '<span id="result"></span>'; 

} else { $selected_faction = '<span id="result"></span>';

echo '<div class="faction_text">Joined: '.$selected_faction.'.</div>';

}
```

when I:

> echo $selected_faction;

in the if statement, it gets the right faction value (i'm using custom jquery drop down boxes by the way here).

The problem is that this id is not being passed to the else statement where i can update the database.   I'm really not sure how I would pass the id on to the else statement.

> echo $selected_faction is blank in the else clause

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: > The problem is that this id is not being passed to the else statement where i can update the database. I'm really not sure how I would pass the id on to the else statement.

what do you mean there?

Comment: The jquery function inserts the selected id into: <span id="result">'id inserted here'</span>.   But, i can't get that jquery inserted value into a php variable to update my MySQL database.  Have i explained my situation better?

Comment: So you want to get data that is inserted into an element by Javascript _after_ the page has been generated by PHP?

Comment: If its possible, from your reply, i'm guessing its not ^^.  Any alternate ideas you may have on achieving this are appreciated :).
Maybe AJAX?

Comment: None of this is PHP5 specific, please tag correctly. http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to send the content of that div back to your server with AJAX.

You could start learning here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

I suppose a good starting point might be: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I've declared $selected_faction outside the block as you've stated, but it still returns = Joined: . / $selected_faction = ' ';

How do i pass on the value inside the <span id="result"></span> to my else statement?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the value inside the span?

Comment: Do you mean this line: `echo $selected_faction = '<span id="result"></span>'; `?

Comment: yeah, the javascript inserts the selected id in that span.

Comment: i've tried this, and it still doesn't display a value (when $selected_faction = '<span id="result"></span>';)  outside the if !isset brackets.  I think the problem is that jquery inserts the selected id inside: <span id="result"></span> when a drop down item is selected, i can't get this id into a php variable for me to use.

Comment: It's not going to. Edited answer.